# Hibernate proxies - classes with unusual names

Tags: grails

While doing some GORM research to better my understanding of GORM, I was using a practice Grails project where I had a `Pet` domain class. I came across a casting error where I noticed in the error message there was a class with a name like `Pet_$$_javassist_3`. Is this a hibernate proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is an instance of a Proxy class.